/bin, /sbin symlinks mysteriously breaking, init file disappearing. How to debug?
Similar to here, but no solution was found for them either. I also tried checking the history, see if something was running 'rm' but no dice.
Periodically, my device stops responding. The only commands I can use are builtin shell commands such as cd, echo, pwd.
Any other command such as ls (bin) or fsck (sbin)... all show
-bash: /usr/bin/ls: no such file or directory, yet the files still exist.
If I cd into /usr/bin and run echo *, I see a list of all the commands that supposedly cannot be found. ls, sudo, ect... , but I cannot execute them. Attempting to manually execute /usr/bin/ls results in the same error.
I checked my path variable... it seemed fine
echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin

The only files I noticed missing were usr/bin/init and usr/sbin/init (thus prompting the boot to initramfs on restart). Additionally, under root / the
/bin and /sbin folders were gone, possibly the symlinks were missing? On a working install, there is a symlink between /bin -> /usr/bin
When this occurs, since I have no permissions, and nothing else works, I am forced to restart by powering off/on the machine, followed by it booting to initramfs.
I know a temporary fix to the the issue... From an USB with a fresh install of my distribution, I copy over /bin, /sbin, /lib to my boot partition under /root. But this doesn't solve it permanently, and the issue comes back after a while.
I would really appreciate any help, I'm honestly completely lost as to what to do now.
I have tried...
1. fsck the partitions.
Both my boot partition (mmcblk0p1) & root partition (mmcblk0p2) seem fine. Dirty bit was set on boot partition 0p1, likely due to hard poweroff. 2nd pass determined no issues.
2. badblocks found 0 bad blocks in its read test
3. Memtest the device I haven't been able to memtest it yet, as I cannot figure out how to get my device to boot to it. I flashed memtest to an SD card, as well as a usb. My device won't boot from either. I don't have a bios, it's running u-boot. Supposedly, I can interrupt the u-boot process to select where to boot, but pressing keys does nothing during boot. Someone here suggests it may be that there isn't USB support for the keyboard in u-boot, only once it boots to linux... making it impossible to boot from another drive? The device is an Orange Pi 5B, with Ubuntu 22.04 flashed to the EMMC drive built onto the device.
4. Test the PSU I am running with this 5v 4a PSU, people Here seem to have similar issues. How can I test if my PSU is the issue, or if nothing else, can someone suggest one that wont have problems, so I can rule the PSU issue out?

(I'd have preferred to ask some questions in a comment before attempting to answer, but I don't have enough reputation. Hopefully this answer will put you on the right track, though.)
It sounds a lot like your issue is a consequence of something going wrong with usrmerge, or perhaps with the follow-up usr-is-merged diversion.
If you are running Ubuntu >=20.04 and <=23.10, you should have a package usrmerge installed. Check whether it is installed properly with dpkg -l usrmerge; if the output does not have a line beginning ii usrmerge, then try (re)installing it with apt-get reinstall usrmerge.
If you are running Ubuntu >=23.10, then your system should already have been through usrmerge, in which case it should have these (empty) directories in the root directory:
/bin.usr-is-merged
/lib.usr-is-merged
/sbin.usr-is-merged

These are installed by the virtual package usr-is-merged, provided by base-files. If you are running >=23.10 and these directories are missing, then perhaps they have been accidentally deleted? In this case apt-get reinstall base-files might fix the issue.

I think this is a hardware issue unrelated to usrmerge

Running Ubuntu 22.04. Tried dpkg -l usrmerge, but it looks fine to me, shows ... ii usrmerge 25ubuntu2 ...

You mentioned that the init symlink had disappeared. This should be provided by the systemd-sysv package. Is that installed properly?

The temporary nature (fixed by reboot) of this makes me think that your disk is going offline.
I would normally suspect the drive is failing, but you say badblocks finds no issues.  It might also be helpful looking at smartctl -a for the drive.   Possibly the drive controller is failing but the media is fine.  However, even if the drive is not failing, this could be a firmware bug in the drive, or a bad/loose cable or a bad power supply giving the drive brown outs.
Checking kernel messages (dmesg) when it goes offline might be illuminating.
It might help to open a text virtual console and just have it follow the kernel messages continuously (or assign it as kernel console or have syslog dump messages there or something) so that you can still see the messages without running anything after it crashes.

It is not fixed directly by rebooting. The reboot fails, loading to initramfs. I need to manually copy over the missing folders before it starts again. I tried doing a smartctl scan, but smartctl does not support my eMMC. I've tried different cables, but haven't seen any difference. I will try printing the kernel messages continuously though, seems like a good idea. Thanks!

Sounds like maybe your SSD has failed and has gone read only.  It only pretends to accept writes.   This is typical failure mode for a ssd that has run out of replacement blocks and is at end of its life.  There is an nvme tool similar to smartctl that may work.

Hmm, I just got the machine a few months ago, though its possible the drive was faulty. If the drive had failed though, wouldn't it reject any writes? After copying the folders, I can use the system fine (saving files, rebooting, ect, all work, at least until it bricks itself). Do you think its worth running a write test with badblocks? I'm not entirely sure how to do it though, since I can't seem to get it to boot from any other media devices.

The written folders may reside only in cache.  If they revert after reboot, that's probably what's hppening.  You should never write with badblocks on an ssd.  It doesn't fix anything, it just wears it out faster.

Ah, ok. Just went and double checked, written folders persist after multiple reboots. I will try ordering another PSU. Another thing I noticed is the reddit post from a guy with a similar problem, was supposedly caused by his Wi-Fi card..??
Final comment
states the problem was his TP-Link T3U plus wifi adapter. I am using a TP-Link AC1300.

Could very well be the same problem. No idea how / why... but i'm going to try just unplugging the card and see if it no longer crashes. Also printing the kernel messages in case still does.
